# Why are freestanding code blocks allowed?

Tags: javascript

I was bitten by a bug recently.  I had code like this:

```
if (x == 1)
{
    do_stuff();
}
else
{
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

However, I had mistakenly omitted the word `else`, and so the second code block was always executed.

What is the rationale for allowing such freestanding code blocks?  I assume there's a good reason.

Comment: Presently they're handy for block-scoping (with `let` and `const`), though I'm not sure it speaks to the initial rationale as that's a recent addition, relatively speaking.

Comment: You can do that in almost all languages

Comment: This feels like it's probably a consequence of JavaScript's extremely short concept-to-market timespan. It probably worked fine until some other feature was added and they didn't have time to check/fix it until it was too late.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of it like this… It's not so much that *free-standing* blocks are a special construct allowed by the language, but rather that such blocks are a *kind of* statement. Quoting [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block):

> A **block statement** (or **compound statement** in other languages) is used to group zero or more statements.

This means that constructs like `if` / `else` can be defined as

```
if (<<expression>>) <<statement>> [ else <<statement>> ]
```

And the language can then treat the following as the same thing because both `foo()` and `{ foo(); }` are statements:

```
if (true) foo();
if (true) { foo(); }
```

---

You said you were 'bitten' by this due to a typo. Although lone blocks are a core feature of the language, they could be a sign of a logic error or code smell. If you'd like to catch issues like this early, I'd recommend installing [eslint](https://eslint.org/) on your project. In particular the [`no-lone-blocks`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-lone-blocks) rule could catch this specific bug. With this rule enabled, the following code:

```
if (x == 1)
{
    do_stuff();
}
{
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

Will generate the error:

> Block is redundant. (no-lone-blocks)

Answer (score 5):

> The block statement is often called compound statement in other languages. It allows you to use multiple statements where JavaScript expects only one statement. Combining statements into blocks is a common practice in JavaScript. The opposite behavior is possible using an empty statement, where you provide no statement, although one is required.

> The block is delimited by a pair of curly brackets and may optionally be [labelled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (meaning it can be used with break or continue statements)

Additionally, it allows for block scoped variables by using `let` or `const`

```js
var x = 'Function scope'; {
  let x = 'Block Scope';
  console.log(x);
}

console.log(x);
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block

Comment: That is really a side effect ... `let` and `const` are very recent language additions whereas `{}` blocks are not

Comment: I've slightly modified your answer so that it appears as a quote. Not an issue of course, but indicating that it was taken directly from the citation seemed appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

A [block statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/block) is just to have a grouping possibility for compound statements.

This allows to [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) a run inside of a function or outsite without using a `return` statement.

```js
var a = 10;

block: {
    if (a === 10) break block;

    console.log('still in block');
}

console.log('outside block');
```

Answer (score 1):

`if`, `else`, `for`, `do` and `while` expect *one* statement.

Blocks are just a way to execute several statements -or none- where one is expected.

Freestanding blocks are allowed for the same reason that freestanding statements are allowed. This code would also fail if you forget the `else`, because `do_other_stuff()` would always be executed:

```
if (x == 1)
    do_stuff();
else
    do_other_stuff();
```